# I need to retrieve primary, secondary category and source from JSON data and list it in a listView. And on running the app I get an empty listView

Tags: android, json

if supplier id is !=0 then

```
                    if(user.getString("iSupplierID")!="0")                          
                    {                               
                            String SUPPLIER_NAME=user.getString(TAG_NAME);  
                            String PRIMARY_SERVICE_CATEGORY = user.getString(TAG_PRIMARY);
                            String SECONDARY_SERVICE_CATEGORY = user.getString(TAG_SECONDARY);
                            String SOURCE_DIRECTORY_TYPE = user.getString(TAG_SOURCE);
```

Adding value HashMap key => value

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, SUPPLIER_NAME);
                            map.put(TAG_PRIMARY, PRIMARY_SERVICE_CATEGORY);
                            map.put(TAG_SECONDARY, SECONDARY_SERVICE_CATEGORY);
                            map.put(TAG_SOURCE, SOURCE_DIRECTORY_TYPE);
                            supplierlist.add(map);
```

creating an id for list view

```
lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

listview adapter

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SupplierDetails.this, supplierlist,
                                    R.layout.list_view,
                                    new String[] { TAG_NAME,TAG_PRIMARY,TAG_SECONDARY, TAG_SOURCE }, new int[] {
                                        R.id.primary,R.id.secondary, R.id.source});
                                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Follow this link . :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
It's best example and it's give which you wants.

Comment: i need to get an id from user and display respective details.

Comment: i am still getting an empty list